# Firebase hosting rewrite for external wordpress under /blog path

Tags: reactjs, wordpress, firebase, url-rewriting, firebase-hosting

I'm working on a React app hosted on Firebase, and a Wordpress blog hosted on Godaddy.

Is it possible to have the Wordpress blog rendering under /blog ?

I tried something like this in firebase.json (handeling multiple targets):

```
 "hosting": [
    {
      "target": "site1",
      "public": "site1/public",
      "rewrites": [
        {
          "source": "/blog/**",
          "destination": "myblog.example.com"
        }
      ]
    },
    ...
 ]
```

But I'm getting the 404 page from the React app.

I know I can rewrite to a Cloud Function, but how to "proxy" to the external blog, preventing the app to "catch" the request ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't rewrite to arbitrary URLs -- to accomplish this you'd need to deploy a Cloud Function that proxied to the Wordpress blog using e.g. [node-http-proxy](https://github.com/http-party/node-http-proxy). You could also use [Cloud Run](https://cloud.google.com/run) to host the Wordpress blog directly and [rewrite to the Cloud Run service](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/cloud-run).

Comment: The http-proxy is what I needed. Thanks for pointing me to the right direction.

Comment: So this means you can't rewrite urls to your static assets, images etc - to the external image CDN you would be using? That's totally lame.